# Error message when trying to ask a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been trying to ask a question, but an error about the message body is given. This is the question:

> Can someone help me with this?
>
> Given that x, y are positive integers with x(x + 1)jy(y + 1), but neither x nor x + 1 divides either of y or y + 1, and x2+ y2 as small as possible, find x^2+ y^2.
>
> I tried looking at the values, and it seems neither x or x+1 or the y's are prime. :

I don't know how to change it so it will be accepted.

Comment: What did the error message say?  (If it was something about "quality standards" perhaps [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/214632).)

Comment: IT seems that the OP succeeded in [posting the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543550/number-theory-contest-problem).